# How do I "freeze" an nfs mount in kubernetes to snapshot it if fsfreeze sends operation not permitted?

Tags: kubernetes, filesystems, snapshot, kubernetes-pvc

I have an NFS based PVC in a kubernetes cluster that I need to freeze to take a snapshot of.  I tried fsfreeze, but I get "operation not supported".  I assume because it is trying to freeze the entire nfs instead of just the mount. I have checked and I can freeze the filesystem on the side of the NFS server. Is there a different way that I can stop writes to the filesystem to properly sync everything?

Comment: is it even possible to do a snapshot of nfs volume?

Comment: @VasiliAngapov im trying to get a backup of the data in the  mount of that volume so that I can migrate it out. In this specific case, using velero and restic. snapshot was likely the wrong term, but it was the best one I was aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero/issues/2042 and some other quick poking around, fsfreeze doesn't support NFS mounts. In general it seems to mostly on work with real local volumes which you'll almost never use with Kubernetes.

Comment: Any alternative solution exists at client side so NFS snapshot can have time-based consistency? Can we firmly say that no possibilities left on NFS client side?

Comment: I can think of `kill -SIGSTOP pid` and `kill -SIGCONT pid`.

Comment: You can use COW filesystems perhaps to temporarily force all changes into an overlay but then not clear how you would sync that back. The real answer is that you do the backup on the NFS server, not the client side.